# How to implement a form with nested fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

There are two related models

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    """Information about an employee's skills."""

    LEVELS = (
        ('basic', 'Basic'),
        ('intermediate', 'Intermediate'),
        ('advanced', 'Advanced'),
        ('expert', 'Expert'),
    )

    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee_skills")
    technology = models.ForeignKey(Technology, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.CharField('common year using amount ', max_length=4)
    last_year = models.CharField('Last year of technology using ', max_length=4)
    level = models.CharField("experience level", max_length=64, choices=LEVELS)

class Technology(models.Model):
    """Technologies."""

    name = models.CharField('technology name', max_length=32, unique=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Techgroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group")
```

The point is that each technology has its own meaning for the level of ownership, years of experience and when it was last used. 
I made a form that allows  to edit one technology at a time.

**forms.py**

```
class SkillEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(1, 11)]
    LAST_YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(1980, datetime.datetime.now().year + 1)]
    year = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Select(choices=YEAR_CHOICES),
    )
    last_year = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=LAST_YEAR_CHOICES))

    class Meta:

        model = Skill
        fields = ['technology', 'level', 'last_year', 'year']
```

There are dozens of technologies in the database. Now I want to implement the ability to edit all the technologies in one window at once, so that the user does not have to press the button to add technology 10 times.

Smth like:

```
technology1   level last_year  year
......
......
technology_N   level last_year  year

<button>
```

And that's where I'm stuck on how to implement it. I would be grateful for the advice.

Comment: There's no pure django solution, you'll need to use javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit multiple models in a single view, you will have to render and process multiple ModelForms based on those models.
A common solution for create/update operations on multiple model instances is [django's formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/).
I would advise you to use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) and `inlineformset_factory`, as it does make things a lot easier.
Don't forget to include the [management form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) in your templates as that can cause a lot of trouble when processing formsets.

On the front-end side of things something like [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) can do the job, if you don't want to write much JavaScript.